# Can a python list be made with two other lists?

Tags: python, list, merge, concatenation, extend

So for example this code here:

```
one = [0,1]
two = [2,3]
three = [one, two]
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can try `print(three)` to see the result. It makes `list` of `lists`.

Comment: So i can add a list in another list

Comment: yes, but **note** that it is reference of list in above case. Suppose you change an element of `one` then, it effects `three`.

Comment: Yes, Python lists can hold other lists; moreover, there are no type restrictions on what list can hold: `[[1,2,3], "cat", 55]` is a valid list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As student said, definitely try the output in your python interactive ide before posting. That being said, you can even do:

```
three = one + two
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `[one, two]`, it will write the lists in that list eg `[[0],[1]]`. If you want a single list then add them like `one + two`.

```
>>> one = [0,1]
>>> two = [2,3]
>>> three = [one, two]
>>> three
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
>>>
>>> three = one + two
>>> three
[0, 1, 2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: This is a useful example - but using some words to explain what's going on, specifically the difference between the original attempt and yours will help make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `+` operator:

```
three = one+two
```

Or if version is > python 3:

```
three = [*one, *two]
```

Or can do `extend`:

```
three=one.copy()
three.extend(two)
```

In all examples:

```
print(three)
```

Will output:

```
[0,1,2,3]
```